# Apache ignores utm_source on GoDaddy hosting?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am accessing a webpage with `utm_source` and apache simply removes it from the `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` entry. any ideas why?

[image: utm_source was removed!]

Comment: find a decent hosting company or setup your own vps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems GoDaddy removes it:
https://www.godaddy.com/help/managed-wordpress-and-query-strings-in-urls-12427